# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation in Laravel

Tags: mysql, exception, laravel-5

When I click submit(save) button for make a Job... then I got below exception.... (**user_name** field already posited as hidden in the **job.create.blade** view form)

Could you tell me where can I modify for fix? 
Thanks.

[image]

**(3/3) QueryException**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`admin-db`.`jobs`,
>   CONSTRAINT `jobs_customer_name_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_name`)
>   REFERENCES `customers` (`customer_name`)) (SQL: insert into `jobs`
>   (`user_name`, `customer_name`, `job_place`, `job_type`, `note_1`,
>   `time_used`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (John, 1, Kontor,
>   Domene og Webhotell, asdf, , 2017-10-08 00:23:40, 2017-10-08
>   00:23:40))

**timestamp_create_users_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';            
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('name')->index();
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**timestamp_create_customers_table.php**

```
public function up()
{        
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('customer_name')->index();
        $table->string('customer_email');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

**timestamp_create_jobs_table.php**

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('user_name')->index();
        $table->string('customer_name')->index();        
        $table->string('job_place');
        $table->string('job_type');
        $table->string('note_1');
        $table->time('time_used')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('user_name')->nullable()->references('name')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('customer_name')->nullable()->references('customer_name')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Model relationship define in:  Job.php**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}
```

**Model relationship define in:  Customer.php**

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by myself...

The problem was using in **pluck method**.
below is well working after modified it.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::label('customer_name', 'Customer Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('customer_name', $searchdata->pluck('customer_name', 'customer_name')->all(), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```